# Create WPF control to displaying vector icon

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm attemping to study from [Material Design for XAML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) source code.

Here is their GitHub:

- [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)

Here is the the code I'm looking into:

- [PackIcon](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/PackIcon.cs)

Here is the helper class for PackIcon:

- [PackIconBase](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/e9200ba3d6cb1f24a679d7f0429b925caaf93eac/paket-files/ControlzEx/ControlzEx/src/ControlzEx/PackIconBase.cs)
- [PackIconDataFactory](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/PackIconDataFactory.cs)

Currently, I'm looking at their icon pack example and doing a quick test on it.

Here is the test class:

```
public class PackIconTest : Control
{
    static PackIconTest()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PackIconTest), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PackIconTest)));
    }

    public PackIconTest()
    {
        Data = "M4.93,4.93C3.12,6.74 2,9.24 2,12C2,14.76 3.12,17.26 4.93,19.07L6.34,17.66C4.89,16.22 4,14.22 4,12C4,9.79 4.89,7.78 6.34,6.34L4.93,4.93M19.07,4.93L17.66,6.34C19.11,7.78 20,9.79 20,12C20,14.22 19.11,16.22 17.66,17.66L19.07,19.07C20.88,17.26 22,14.76 22,12C22,9.24 20.88,6.74 19.07,4.93M7.76,7.76C6.67,8.85 6,10.35 6,12C6,13.65 6.67,15.15 7.76,16.24L9.17,14.83C8.45,14.11 8,13.11 8,12C8,10.89 8.45,9.89 9.17,9.17L7.76,7.76M16.24,7.76L14.83,9.17C15.55,9.89 16,10.89 16,12C16,13.11 15.55,14.11 14.83,14.83L16.24,16.24C17.33,15.15 18,13.65 18,12C18,10.35 17.33,8.85 16.24,7.76M12,10A2,2 0 0,0 10,12A2,2 0 0,0 12,14A2,2 0 0,0 14,12A2,2 0 0,0 12,10Z";
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey DataPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(nameof(Data), typeof(string), typeof(PackIconTest), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DataPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    [TypeConverter(typeof(GeometryConverter))]
    public string Data
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(DataPropertyKey, value); }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML usage:

```
<local:PackIconTest Width="200" Height="200"/>
```

The icon doesn't show. What am I missing?

Comment: You have created a control with a Data property of type string, and assigned a property value in the control's constructor. That's all. There is no code that takes the Data value and turns it into some kind of drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this propblem by making a style applying for PackIconTest target type.

Here is the xaml code:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:PackIconTest">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Path Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Data}"
                          Stroke="Black"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```